# Installing Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I accidentally installed Ubuntu and now I am trying to install Windows 7 again, but when I go into BIOS, the only bootable device I can find is Ubuntu, and not the Windows 7 installation DVD I have inserted in my CD-ROM. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On boot, try pressing F12 to set a temp boot device, and you should be able to boot off the DVD. You can also set the boot order in BIOS.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

There is a key (usually F8-F12) that lets you pick which device you want to boot from. If you're using that and not seeing the DVD drive, check the boot order in the BIOS and make sure the DVD drive is enabled and added to the boot order.

If you can't see the drive in BIOS, check if it's accessible from Ubuntu, it might be faulty. Also, make sure to try another DVD, your Windows disc could be dead. (These might be stupid suggestions but they've worked for me a few times...)

Once you get the DVD working, if you haven't done anything with Ubuntu yet, it's probably best to wipe the disk and install Windows, then Ubuntu again. Getting Windows working alongside Linux is much harder than getting Linux working alongside Windows.